# getting.cpp:235: error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'cv::setSize

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am building image processing classifier the whole code in right except this line

```
recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))
```

My code:

```
    import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import pickle



os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(BASE_DIR)


image_dir =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images") #immages is the picture's folder
print(image_dir)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/lucai/Desktop/python/tutorial/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()





current_id = 0
label_ids = {}
y_labels =[]
x_train = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("jpg"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            label = os.path.basename(root).replace(" ", "-").lower()
            print(label, path)
            if label in label_ids:
                pass
            else:
                label_ids[label] = current_id
                current_id += 1

            id_ = label_ids[label]
            print(label_ids)
            pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L") #grays scale
            image_array = np.array(pil_image,  dtype=np.uint8)  #"uint8",
            print(image_array)
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

            for (x, y,w,h) in faces:
                roi = image_array[y:y+h, x:h+w]
                x_train.append(roi) #roi=region of interest
                y_labels.append(id_)





#print(y_labels)
#print(x_train)

with open ("labels.pickle", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(label_ids , f )  #accumulare le label di training

recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))
recognizer.save("trainer.ylm")
```

And the last two lines gives me this error:

```
recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:235: error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'cv::setSize'
```

Anyone could help?